# Enviar datos de usuarios registrados en una web de WordPress a una web en ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos, wordpress

He buscado por un par de horas y no he obtenido casi nada de información al respecto sobre cómo enviar los datos de los usuarios registrados en una web con WP a una base de datos externa de una web en ASP.net de forma automática.

Actualización con más detalles:

El enlace de registro es: [ISHA](http://ishameetings.cl/sign_in/)

No se si posible crear un "disparador" en WordPress y luego enviar los datos automáticamente a esta web [9th ISHA Annual Scientific Meeting](http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com) que está realizada en ASP.net. Utilizo PHPMyAdmin y no se que tipo de incompatibilidades se podrían producir, ya que desconozco el manejo de base datos de la otra web.

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: Los datos de MySQL se pueden bajar con `mysqldump` y los subes con las herramientas que existan para la otra base de datos. No se necesita más. A menos que tengas características o requisitos que no estés contando. Por lo tanto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía al pie de la letra: [mcve].

Comment: una idea: del MySQL exporta como CSV, luego importas en el SQL Server desde un CSV :D

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero los datos deben enviarse automáticamente a la base de datos de la otra web cuando el usuario se registra.

Comment: de nada América! acabo de responder, espero que la respuesta te pueda dar una guía, si necesitas ayuda aquí estamos en SOes para servir, que tengas un bonito día, éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con lo que acabas de responder ya me quedo claro, en ese caso necesitas lo siguiente:

En el lado de ASP.net

- Un token: para evitar que se registren hasta por las puras.
- Un servicio web con WebAPI que es más sencillo que WCF, por ejemplo `http://misitioweb.com/api/registrar`
- CORS habilitado para el origen de sólo tu sitio web en Wordpress.

En el lado del Wordpress

- Necesitas lanzar POST a 'http://misitioweb.com/api/registrar' (tu portal en ASP.net) justo después del registro de cada usuario.

Ahora bien, para realizar esto de Wordpress sí o sí vas a necesitar echarla un ojo a la documentación oficial en https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/ y https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

El código fuente se encuentra en `user_register` que está en `/wp-includes/user.php` en la función `wp_insert_user()`

Te dejo un ejemplo de referencia:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

    //Aquí es donde tienes que lanzar el POST        
}
```

Si deseas algo simple, el token que sea un GUID, de tal manera que en la petición al server .net preguntes si coincide y de ser cierto, continúas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Fredy, a partir del día lunes le comentaré a mis compañeros y al encargado de la web en ASP.net para comenzar a crear el puente entre estos dos proyectos.

Comment: de nada, estamos para servir :D éxitos con el proyecto, dale con todo el power 2.0!

Comment: lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Deje ese trabajo hace 2 meses, pero yo creo que se completo gracias a tus sugerencias.

Comment: me alegra mucho saberlo :D  ¡de nada! Te agradecería que marques la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio (efecto de % de preguntas resueltas). Saludos